# A program that calculate salaries in python

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

```
value_ = float(input("Value: "))
values = [0.0, 0.4, 0.6]
for value in values:
    g_value = 0.6 + 0.1
    values.append(g_value)
while value_ not in values:
    print("This value are never used")
    value_ = float(input("Value: "))
performance = ''
Raise = 2400
if value_ == 0.0:
    performance = 'Unacceptable performance'
    Raise = Raise * value_
elif value_ == 0.4:
    performance = 'Acceptable performance'
    Raise = Raise * value_
elif value_ >= 0.6:
    performance = 'Meritorious performance'
    Raise = Raise * value_
print('Performance: ', performance, '\n', 'Raise: ', Raise, '$')
```

I had tried this code and it works but without this for loop

```
for value in values:
    g_value = 0.6 + 0.1
    values.append(g_value)
```

I meant by this loop any number greater than 0.6
Any thoughts how to solve it!!!!

Comment: What is your expected output from that loop? `0.6 + 0.1` will always be `0.7`, are you just trying to append `0.7` to the list a certain number of times? Or did you mean to include `value` somewhere in that calculation?

Comment: I wanted it to be any number greater than 0.6

Comment: You want _what_ to be "any number greater than 0.6"?  Please look at how to create a [mcve] and show only the minimum code to reproduce your issue. For example "My input is `...`, my loop is `...` and my expected output is a list that looks like `...`

Comment: then after I look can you help me in that!!!!!!!